# How to handle Android FCM Messages when application is in Background with data payload?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Android push notification using FCM is unable to handle when application in background. Default message is displayed in notification tray.

Can Anyone help me how to handle the messages when application in background.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```

}

This method is not called when application is in background. Any help will be great help for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42268901/7320259 check this

Comment: That's how notification messages works ... As it is stated in documentation there are 2 messages types ... It is also written how they work.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ try this it helps you for background notification

Comment: androidhive is a bad tutorial source also it is from 2012 so it is obsoleted(as it is using GCM not FCM)

Comment: @ZakiPathan Hello man.. your stackoverflow reference is good. But the issue is where I have to implement the logic which is mentioned in stackoverflow. Because I dont have any control over the code when app goes to background.

Comment: if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) condition check for app in background or foreground

Comment: @ZakiPathan I got what you are trying to say. My issue here is "onMessageReceived" block is not getting called when app is in backgorund. If the above method is called means your reference is good and will be implemented. Can You suggest why onMessageReceived method not getting called.

Comment: *My issue here is "onMessageReceived" block is not getting called when app is in backgorund* ... again that's how messages of type notification works **you cannot change it** , you need to send message of second type ... what is a second type and how to send it ? it is all in the FCM's documentation (and in thousands of similar questions, here on stackoverflow - internet search: "onmessagereceived not called")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onMessageReceived() will be always called if you receive the payload as "data" always from server.

**Example :** 
Payload from server should be like following :

```
{
 "data":{
 "id": 1,
 "missedRequests": 5
 "addAnyDataHere": 123
 },
 "to":"fhiT7evmZk8:APA91bFJq7Tkly4BtLRXdYvqHno2vHCRkzpJT8QZy0TlIGs......"
}
```

for more about this issue. Please refer following URL :       [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already found this was the issue still upvoted for your correct suggestion.

Comment: i don't get it even if the data payload is coming from server, i can log that when in foregound only

Comment: Whole payload should be in the "data".

Comment: A mix of notification payload and data payload will result in message that will not be handled in the background. So be sure, you strip of all the notification payload!