# Android FCM show notification with triggering service

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to implement FCM in my app but I have a problem. Whenever I send the notification, instead of calling my custom code, it just show the default notification. What am I doing wrong?

Those are the **services**:

```
<service
    android:name="com.backgroundws.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name="com.backgroundws.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And this is my **Java** code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMessaging", "GotMessage");
        WSListener.sendEvent(this, "Push");
    }

}
```

And I see this in the logcat when I get the notification on the device:

```
I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_SCHEDULE, mPermissionType:0
I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_SCHEDULE, mPermissionType:0
```

This is how I send the notifications:

```
function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message, $url, $key) {
        $fields = array(

            'to'                   => $reg_id ,
            'priority'             => "high",
            "notification"         => array("body"=>$message),
            'data'                 => array( "url"=> $url)
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: key=' . $key
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            //die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;

    }
```

Of course I tested and the path to the service is correct.

Comment: care to add the most important info, the notification data?

Comment: edited. The key and the reg_id are correct, since I do get the notification.

Comment: I don't want to decipher your php. Show the actual json data

Comment: try to send $'message' inside 'data' only. remove 'notification'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your server's content with notification in both modes(Background and Foreground), You have to send payload from server inside 'data' only.
For more you can refer here [How to handle Android FCM Messages when application is in Background with data payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388990/how-to-handle-android-fcm-messages-when-application-is-in-background-with-data-p/42399338#42399338)